# How to set value of lookup field in a new entity in CRM using C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, lookup, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to update a Lookup field in CRM via the following code.

- Create a new entity *Person*
- Person contains a lookup field `HospitalOfBirth` from another entity *Hospital*
- Value to be inserted: hospitalName

---

I referenced from online articles and drafted my code below.

```
Entity Person = new Entity("Person");

//do I set the value of the field by the following?
Person.Attributes[Person.HospitalOfBirth] = hospitalName;

Person.Attributes[Person.HospitalOfBirth] = new EntityReference("Hospital", Person.Id);

Person.Id = helper.GetOrganizationService().Create(Person);
```

May I know to assign a value to the lookup field `HospitalOfBirth` in *Person*, and update it with hospitalName?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set a lookup value by display name text, you need lookup Id (Foreign key) to achieve it.

If you just have the `hospitalName` and not the `hospitalId`, then you have to query the `Hospital` entity for the GUID by doing **RetrieveMultiple** using **FetchXml** or **QueryExpression** by passing `hospitalName` filter.

```
Person.Attributes[Person.HospitalOfBirth] = new EntityReference("Hospital", Hospitalid);
```

Comment: Thank you @Arun!

Answer (score 1):

```
Entity Person = new Entity("Person");
Person.Attributes[Person.HospitalOfBirth] = new EntityReference("Hospital", Person.Id);
Person.Id = **<<Guid of the Person record you need to update>>**
helper.GetOrganizationService().Update(Person);
```

You need to provide the guid of the record you want to update in the entity object.

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: I'm sorry,I am creating a new `Person`. I'll update my title. May I know where does the insertion of value `hospitalName` gets executed?